# Problemas em converter px para Porcentagem

Tags: javascript, css3, porcentagem

Eu tenho esse código :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;background:#65C6BB;position:absolute;transform: translate(20px,0px);">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Queria converter a propriedade CSS 'transform' para porcentagem também.

Estou usando a regra :
`(100 / window.innerWidth) *pixels`

Só que fazendo isso meu resultado pra uma Window Width de 1920 é de : 1.0416666666666667 ...

Se eu substituir isso na propriedade CSS 'transform' assim :

`transform: translate(1.0416666666666667%,0px);`

A div não irá ficar na mesma posição. Já tentei usando window.document.body.offsetWidth mas também não funciona.

Alguém sabe qual é a solução?

Answer (score 1):

Transformar usando % move o elemento com relação ao tamanho do elemento e não o tamanho do seu pai. Então a formula deveria ser

`(100 / element.offsetWidth) * pixels`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021726/css-transform-with-convert-from-px-dont-work